# Does $\frac{n^a}{a^n}$ converge or diverge? $a$ is Natural Number

Tags: analysis

I Applied the Ratio test and it all cancelled apart from $\frac{1}{a}$ so this would suggest the series converges, however wolfram alpha says it diverges.
Whats going on?

Sorry this has been editied a thousand times. This is what i want to know.

Comment: What kind of sequence is $a_n$?

Comment: What series? I can only see a sequence. And what is $a$?

Comment: There are too many edits going on. I am rolling back to the OP. In the event of ambiguous notation, ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: @MathsPro Is it $\frac{n^a}{an}$ or $\frac{n^a}{a} n$?

Comment: @MathsPro, please clarify your sequence first.

Comment: I'm editing you question, check if it is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i want to know. Ratio test says 1/a does it not? and hence coverges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ratio test, we consider
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left\vert \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \right\vert
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^a/a^{n+1}}{n^a/a^n}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^a \frac{1}{a}
= \frac{1}{a}$$
which is the answer you found.

We know that the series converges if and only if
$$\left\vert \frac{1}{a} \right\vert < 1 \iff \left\vert \,a\, \right\vert > 1$$
So your logic is almost correct: just be careful with the ratio test, as it doesn’t tell us anything about what happens when the ratio is equal to one.

Here, we have equality if $a = 1$, and then the general term reduces to $n$. Clearly this doesn't converge.

So the series does not converge for *all* natural numbers, but it does converge for all natural numbers *greater than one*.

As for the discrepancy between Wolfram Alpha and your logic, I suspect that arises because WA probably doesn't know that $a$ is a natural number.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.